# FileReader: DOMException, Unable to convert blob to arrayBuffer again and again

Tags: javascript, blob, filereader, arraybuffer

I am using fileReader to convert a blob object into arrayBuffer in javascript/React.

then convert the array buffer into blob using
blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);

But Now, when I again read the arrayBuffer from last created Blob,

> I am getting error:

```
DOMException: The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired
```

> Sample Code:

```
let bufferChunk = await convertBlobToBuffer(blobChunk); // get buffer of given slice of file

const blobChunk = new Blob([bufferChunk]); // create blob of buffer bcozz blob does not take much space as taken by arrayBuffer :P

bufferChunk = await convertBlobToBuffer(blobChunk); //This causing ERROR
       
const convertBlobToBuffer = blob => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = err => reject(err || reader.error);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });
};
```